# Append Problem with JSON data to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have problem after showing json data to html table.

The problems;

1. Every time i change the product_id, the table value always add new data.
2. if the result is null, the tbody table still showing the current previous data.

Here's my code:

```
<table class="table" id="history_maintenance">
  <thead>
    <th>Date In</th>
    <th>SPK No</th>
    <th>Purchase No</th>
    <th>Maintenance Notes</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script>
$('#product_id').on('change', function() {

let customer_name = document.getElementById("customer_name").value;
let phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
let car_plate_no = document.getElementById("car_plate_no").value;
let car_type = document.getElementById("car_type").value;
let product_id = document.getElementById("product_id").value;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('spk/get_customer_transaction_history') ?>",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    data: {
        customer_name: customer_name,
        phone: phone,
        car_plate_no: car_plate_no,
        car_type: car_type,
        product_id: product_id,
    },

    success: function(dataHistory) {
      let transactionHistory = '';

      for (i = 0; i < dataHistory.length; i++) {
        transactionHistory += '<tr>';
        transactionHistory += '<td>' + dataHistory[i].date_in + '</td>';
        transactionHistory += '<td>' + dataHistory[i].spk_no + '</td>';
        transactionHistory += '<td>' + dataHistory[i].purchase_no + '</td>';
        transactionHistory += '<td>' + dataHistory[i].spk_maintenance_notes + '</td>';
        transactionHistory += '</tr>';
      }

      $('#history_maintenance tbody').append(transactionHistory);
    }
   });
   return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's what appending means - adding to already existing content. It seems like you just need to overwrite the text content.

Comment: how can i overwrite the text content? i mean what function or article that i can learn to solve that?

Comment: That's just a simple assignment: `yourElement.textContent = yourValue`.

Comment: Or, if you want to stick to jQuery functions, that would be [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString).

Answer (score 0):

thanks @EL_vanja for the tips

i add this:

```
$('#history_maintenance tbody').html('');
```

before:

```
let transactionHistory = '';
```